# Clean approach to finding a folder's parent

Tags: c#, recursion, directory

I have this piece of code that searches for a folder given a starting directory. Once the folder is found I need the name of it's parent. The following piece of code works but it is terribly ugly. I have a flag, "sessionFound" to assist with breaking from nested foreach loops. The following works. I was hoping I could get some eyes on this and see if I could get some suggestions on how to make this less verbose and a bit more concise.

Thanks.

```
    private void SetProjectFolder(string sessionid)
        {

//IoC container gives the root directory to begin search.
            string[] supportDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(ApplicationContainer.SupportDirectory);
            bool sessionFound = false;

            foreach (string directory in supportDirs)
            {
                if (!sessionFound)
                {
                    foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
                    {
                        if (!sessionFound)
                        {
                            foreach (string productSubFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
                            {
                                if (productSubFolder.Contains(sessionid))
                                {
                                    _productName = Directory.GetParent(productSubFolder).Parent.Name;
                                    sessionFound = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void SetProjectFolder(string sessionid)
    {
        //This will simulate the contains statement
        string searchPattern = string.Format("*{0}*", sessionid);
        string[] supportDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(ApplicationContainer.SupportDirectory, searchPattern);

        foreach (string filteredFolder in supportDirs)
        {
            _productName = Directory.GetParent(filteredFolder).Name;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The overloaded Directory.GetDirectories is what I needed. Because I want to search through all of the folders not just he root I used the overload that accepts a SearchOption enum.

Answer (score 0):

By removing `sessionFound` you end up with a pretty clear and straightforward code:

```
private void SetProjectFolder(string sessionid)
{
    //IoC container gives the root directory to begin search.
    string[] supportDirs = Directory.GetDirectories(ApplicationContainer.SupportDirectory);

    // search for product subfolder
    foreach (string directory in supportDirs)
    {
        foreach (string folder in Directory.GetDirectories(directory))
        {
            foreach (string productSubFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(folder))
            {
                if (productSubFolder.Contains(sessionid))
                {
                    // product sub-folder found, set it and exit
                    _productName = Directory.GetParent(productSubFolder).Parent.Name;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // product sub-folder not found
    !!! handle error path
}
```

In case your directory structure is static in the sense of the abovementioned search algorithm, I don't think there's something wrong with the nested `foreach` statements. Maybe you could extract the code starting with the middle `foreach` into a separate method like `string FindProductSubfolderInFolder(Directory)`.